# SwaggerUI Failed to load API definition Python

Tags: python, api, flask, swagger, swagger-ui

I deployed a Python Flask API on a Server and got this Error on the Main Page

```
Fetch errorFailed to fetch http://127.0.0.1:8000/swagger.json
Fetch errorPossible cross-origin (CORS) issue? The URL origin (http://127.0.0.1:8000) does not match the page (xx.xxx.xxx.xx). Check the server returns the correct 'Access-Control-Allow-*' headers.
```

On my local machine, I would get the automatic generated swagger.json.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You may need to enable CORS for this
`https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/`

Comment: I tried this

@api.route('/', methods=['GET'])
@cross_origin()
def get(self):
    return 200, {'ContentType': 'application/json'}

but it doenst work